# Help with a consequence of $V=L$

Tags: set-theory

> Assume $V=L$. Prove that there is a function $f:\omega_1\rightarrow\omega_1$, $\Delta_1$ definable over $L_{\omega_1}$, so that for every $A\subseteq\omega_1$ and every $\Sigma_1$ formula $\varphi$, there is a club $C\subseteq\omega_1$ so that for every $\alpha\in C$, if $L\vDash\varphi[A]$, then $L_{f(\alpha)}\vDash\varphi[A\cap\alpha]$.

I'm assuming that I can prove this more or less immediately from the fact that $\diamondsuit$ is true in $L$, but I'm not actually quite sure how to apply the principle in this case. Any help is appreciated.